# May one order food from Amazon Prime after Pesach?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, internet, chametz-leaven

May one order chametz from a publically-traded company (Amazon) which may have had food pass through any number of distributers on the way? The service in question is Amazon Prime Pantry.

Comment: Why is this different from any other store?

Comment: @DoubleAA i guess not different, OP is asking if we know which suppliers this service uses and if they pose a problem

Comment: I think this is a more interesting question as there is no way to find out who "owns" it.

Comment: AFAIK, Amazon is a non-Jewish owned company. What, then, would be the problem?

Comment: @DanF What if they get the chametz item from a Jew who owned it on Pesach and just ship it? I think that is the question they the OP is asking.

Comment: Note also that there are third party sellers on Amazon that sell on the site as well (even for Prime), and I can personally vouch that at least 1 of them is Jewish.

Comment: Can we assume that the owner of the item is the one who gets the money from your purchase? I'm not referring to direct 3rd party sales. That may be a problem as @Salmononius2 stated. But, when you buy through Amazon, they have it in their inventory or they're making a request for you as an agent. But you pay Amazon, so they "own" the item until you get it. When you return it, who do you return it to? Amazon! Not the supplier. So it seems that Amazon owns these items.

Comment: @sabbahillel Is there a problem with a Gentile buying chametz from a Jew during Pesach, and then you're buying that item from the Gentile after Pesach? See my assumption in ^^^.

Comment: I don't understand the VTC because of *psak halacha*.

Comment: @DanF I don't think that's the case. Amazon acts as a Fulfilment Center for the items (for all items that say something along the lines of "Shipped by Amazon") even if a third party owns it. The fact that Amazon is the payment processor makes no bearing on who owns the item (just like PayPal doesn't own every item that you buy from every website that has a "Pay with PayPal" button). The items that third party sellers send to the Amazon warehouses get handled regarding shipping, returns, etc. as part of the "Fulfilment by Amazon" selling plan.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/costco-after-passover

Comment: *But, when you buy through Amazon, they have it in their inventory or they're making a request for you as an agent.* When you buy it from Amazon, it is theirs if they already have it in their warehouse from before Pesach. If they get it from a Jew during Pesach, the Jew already owned it on Pesach and it is therefore asur even if it was sold to a nonJew **during** Pesach and then sold to you after Pesach.

Comment: Note that this question about [Costco](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/costco-after-passover) deals with the question in a similar manner.

Comment: is there a way to know who each of the sellers are? Benefiting from chametz owned by another Jew is a rabbinical prohibition and it would seem since there is no way to know who the individual sellers are it would make sense to apply the rule of safek d'rabbanon lekula...